# mat-checkbox does not check if condition is false (only on double click)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an entity that has a variable that needs to be the opposite of the checkbox state.

```ts
enitity.enabled = true
```

The checkbox is there to "mark to delete" the item. If you mark and send the form, the item marked is soft deleted.

With this in mind, the checkbox is exactly like this:

```html
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="!entity.enabled">{{!entity.enabled}}</mat-checkbox>
```

For some reason, the `enitity.enabled` value is only changed when the second click applies.

I looked a lot for a solution or if this is a bug, nothing found I came here for your help.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

[Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-checkbox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the negation operator with ngModel.

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="entity.enabled">{{!entity.enabled}}</mat-checkbox>
```

Try it this way.

Another approach is to react on the click- or change-event

HTML

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="entity.enabled" (change)="onChange()">{{!entity.enabled}}</mat-checkbox>
```

TypeScript

```
private onChange(): void {
   this.entity.enabled = !this.entity.enabled;
}

private onClick(): void {
  this.entity.enabled = !this.entity.enabled;
}
```

Comment: I can't, the 'enabled' is a column on the database that determines if the entity is or not soft deleted.

Comment: I see, but with ngModel you only say that you want to two-way-bind to the field entity.enabled. You can't use operators here.

Comment: Yeah, my """workaround""" was to convince the backend team to replace the 'enabled' column with 'disabled' column. Thanks for your feedback ;)

Comment: Please have a look at my additional suggestion. Maybe this works for you.

Comment: Your solution is a good one for someone that doesn't have the possibility to implement the same """workaround""" I used. Thanks again.

Comment: Changing (click) event to (change) event solved me two click problem.